# SQL Insert with AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert 50 values into a DB, the table has two column names, one is an ID column set to auto increment and the other is for a code.

When I attempt to do the insert I get a error.

This is my SQL code:

```
 INSERT INTO Names (Id, Code) 
 VALUES (NULL, 'CodeHere', NULL, 'CodeHere', NULL, 'CodeHERE' );
```

Comment: Since you specify two columms, only two values should be inserted.

Comment: `insert into names(code) values ('code'), ('code2'), ('code3')` is what you want

Comment: Please find the `INSERT INTO` samples in this [page](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO Names VALUES ('CodeHere'),('2CodeHere'),('3CodeHere'),('4CodeHere')
```

just ignore auto increment column.

Answer (score 3):

Don't include the ID column if it is auto increment and split the input to one one value per time

```
INSERT INTO Names (Code) 
VALUES ('CodeHere'),('CodeHere'),('CodeHERE' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 INSERT INTO Names (Id, Code) 
     VALUES (NULL, 'CodeHere'), (NULL, 'CodeHere') ,( NULL, 'CodeHERE' );
```